# Append and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

Im having some problems with an navigation im making and i hope someone can help me out.

I need my current list so that when i push another color of link, it will remove the one chosen and add this one insted. So that i can only have 1 link in the trail at the time.

**HTML**

```
<div class="trail"></div>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a class="orange" href="#">Link1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="black" href="#">Link2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="green" href="#">Link3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.trail {
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.trail > a {
    color:#ffffff;
}
.navigation {
    padding:20px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#ccc;
    list-style:none;
}
.navigation > li > a {
    color:#ffffff;
} 
.orange {
    background-color:orange;
}
.black {
    background-color:black;
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var count = 0;

    $('.navigation > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (count < 1){
            var $addinput = $('.trail').append('<a href="#" class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');            
            $('i').append($addinput);    
            count++;
        } 

    });
```

I also made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/LpX4R/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply empty the trail :

```
$('.navigation > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    var $addinput = $('<a>').addClass(this.className).html(this.innerHTML);
    $('.trail').empty().append($addinput); // <= empty then append
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/SUXW3/)

Note that I also simplified your element creation and removed the string concatenations.

Comment: Ah perfect - and so fast. Cheers it works perfectly. I will accept answer when im allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `.clone()` and `.html()` to finish up your task efficiently.

Try,

```
$('.navigation > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".trail").html($(this).clone());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SUXW3/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.navigation > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.trail a').remove();
    var $addinput = $('.trail').append('<a href="#" class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '">' +     $(this).html() + '</a>');
    $("i").append($addinput);
});
```